# Comparing distribution of a biomarker among patients with overlapping clinical features

Tags: distributions, overlapping-data

I have a question how to compare the distribution of one tested biomarker among patients with different overlapping clinical syndromes.

In my case, I am investigating patients with multiple sclerosis and their clinical symptoms can be attributed to several different syndromes, for example pyramidal, sensory, etc. Moreover, one patient may have two or even 3 syndromes. In my datasheet, I created columns with different syndromes (5 in total), and I encoded all my patients as positive (1) or negative (0). At this moment, I want to compare if the distribution of the tested biomarkers differ among these syndromes. Until now, I was able only to evaluate if it differs within one group, for example among patients with pyramidal syndrome and without it (using Mann-Whitney U test as data is non-parametric). However, this kind of comparison does not allow me to evaluate the overlap of these syndromes as the patient with pyramidal syndrome may also have sensory and brainstem symptoms.

How should I organise my data and what statistical test should I perform to evaluate the distribution of biomarker between different syndrome while keeping in mind their overlap?

Comment: Welcome to CV.  One note: Data cannot be parameteric or non-parametric, that's a quality of tests and models.  Also, can you show a sample of what your data looks like and tell us e.g what your sample size is and about how many people have more than one syndrome, and which pairs of syndromes are common?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @PeterFlom. My sample size is small, only 19 patients because it is a pilot study, preliminary data. The amount of patients positive for one syndrome varies between 1 and 9. You syndromes (pyramidal and sensory) is the most common pair, however, a few patients also have an additional one (3 syndromes at once), while other are positive only for one of them.

Answer (score 1):

In your comment you say that you have 19 patients. With this few, there are very few statistical models you can run without risking overfitting, and statistical tests are unlikely to work very well unless the result is obvious. You could run single t-tests or U tests, but you have already done that.

Since you note that this is a pilot study, I would just give means and SDs (or medians and IQRs) and make a few plots, to show what is going on and demonstrate the need for more data.

The very fact that you have patients with multiple syndromes is a sign that you will need more data if you want to make good models and tests.